# XML validation errors with XMLSchemaSet

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, xsd-validation

I have a schema as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="MyDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="Leaf" />
  <xs:complexType name = "Leaf" mixed="true">
         <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Frame" />
  <xs:complexType name="Frame" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Leaf" type ="Leaf" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Frame" type="Frame" nillable="true"/>
    </xs:sequence>
       <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Version" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MetaData1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MetaData2" type="xs:string" />

        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Page" nillable="false">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Frame" type="Frame" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Basically its a recursive structure. A document can have a list of pages. It must contain atleast 1 page. A Page consists of list of frames. A Frame can have sub-frames or leaf (i.e cannot contain subframes). MetaData1 and MetaData2 are optional and can occur anywhere.

A sample XML would be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
  <Version>1.1</Version>
  <MetaData1>Somemetadata</MetaData1>
  <Page>Page1
       <Frame ID="1">Frame1
          <Frame ID="2">SubFrame1
                <Frame ID="3">SubFrame2
                      <Leaf ID="1">Alone</Leaf>
                </Frame>
               <Leaf ID="2">Alone2</Leaf>
          </Frame>
        </Frame>
        <Frame ID="3">SubFrame3
        </Frame>
 </Page>
 <MetaData2 />
</Document>
```

I am using XmlReaderSettings and XmlSchemaSet to do the XML validation against the schema. For some reason I am getting these 2 errors:

1) {"The element 'Document' has invalid child element 'Metadata2'. List of possible elements expected: 'Page'."}

I think its because it is reading in sequence whereas in my case those elements can appear in any order. I tried doing the xs:all attribute but it doesn't work with maxoccurs=unbounded. Any other way ?

2) {"The element 'Frame' has invalid child element 'Leaf'. List of possible elements expected: 'Frame'."}

Could this be same as (1) ? The error occurs for Leaf ID=2

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on Microsoft .NET, which means you are limited to what XSD 1.0 can offer. `xs:all` compositor only supports particles with `maxOccurs="1"`. That is your first problem.

Your schema definitely doesn't capture the fact that `MetaData1` and `MetaData2` can occur anywhere. `Leaf`, `Frame` and `Page` don't have those elements at all. So you'll have to do something about that.

Regardless, you can't achieve exactly what you want, as described; something has to give. You could choose to prescribe the position of some elements, allow some variability among certain particles, or "tuck away" your repeating elements under a "collection" item. Pages for Page, Frames for Frame, Leafs for Leaf.

Another option I would strongly consider, given the definition you provided for metadata elements and version, and which would not affect an "equivalent" ADO.NET DataSet (assuming it would have been possible in XSD 1.0), would be to use attributes instead.  I'll illustrate for this approach. If you're not sure about the other options, let me know and I'll add some more examples.

Modified XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="MyDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:complexType name = "Leaf" mixed="true">
        <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="metadata"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Frame" mixed="true">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Leaf" type ="Leaf" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:element name="Frame" type="Frame" nillable="true"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="metadata"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Document">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Page" nillable="false">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Frame" type="Frame"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attributeGroup ref="metadata"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="metadata"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:attributeGroup name="metadata">
        <xs:attribute name="metadata1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="metadata2" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:schema>
```

The visualization of the above:

[image: QTAssistant showing XSD diagram]

And the equivalent ADO.NET DataSet (this one is the easiest to use to confirm your description of the model):

[image: QTAssistant showing XSD as ADO.NET DataSet]

The semantically equivalent XML which would validate the above (minimally changed, easy to see the impact of using attributes instead):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document version="1.1" metadata1="Somemetadata" metadata2="">
    <Page>Page1
        <Frame ID="1">Frame1
            <Frame ID="2">SubFrame1
                <Frame ID="3">SubFrame2
                    <Leaf ID="1">Alone</Leaf>
                </Frame>
            </Frame>
        </Frame>
        <Frame ID="3">SubFrame3
        </Frame>
    </Page>
</Document>
```

Diagram of the above XML:

[image: Sample XML]

A more complex sample XML showing a valid instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" version="version1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">
    <Page metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Frame ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
            <Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
            <Frame ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                <Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                <Frame ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                    <Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                </Frame>
                <Frame ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                    <Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                </Frame>
            </Frame>
            <Frame ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                <Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                <Frame ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                    <Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                </Frame>
                <Frame ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                    <Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
                </Frame>
            </Frame>
        </Frame>
    </Page>
    <Page metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Frame ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text<Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
            <Leaf ID="ID1" metadata1="metadata11" metadata2="metadata21">text</Leaf>
        </Frame>
    </Page>
</Document>
```

Comment: It still gives {"The element 'Frame' has invalid child element 'Leaf'. List of possible elements expected: 'Frame'."} error with your schema. 

See my original XML, you are missing Leaf ID="2" node.

Comment: @FrankQ. , See updated post: the content of a frame was supposed to be an unbounded choice of Frame or Leaf. I've fixed it.

Comment: thanks that worked ! One last thing, how do you enforce that a Frame or a Leaf must contain a Text value ? If I don't specify text with them, it still passes validation whereas I want to fail it.

Comment: Sorry, you cannot constrain the text value in complex content/mixed. You'll have to rely on .NET code to do that.